# How to make some kids of registration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to create registration/authorization system in Laravel for some types of users and to set differently privileges. How can I make this in Laravel based on standard artisan auth?

So, now I have standart class `AuthController` for custom registration.  Should I create a new the same class for different type of user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel 5.2 supports Multi Auth  please read [this section of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) that will explain what needs to be done to add another driver.

if you are looking for a laravel 5.1 heres a [package](https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth) for it